# Error at top of program when trying to run java code

Tags: java, selenium

I have a simple selenium project I want to run to make sure I have all the configurations down

I am getting this error:

> multiple markers at this line the type
>   org.openqa.selenium.HasInputDevices cannot be resolved. It is
>   indirectly referenced from .class files

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;      
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;  
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;     
public class Tester {               
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                 // Creating a new instance of the HTML unit driver

                 WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

                 // Navigate to Google      
                 driver.get("http://www.google.com");                   

                 // Locate the searchbox using its name     
                 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q")); 

                // Enter a search query     
                element.sendKeys("Guru99"); 

                // Submit the query. Webdriver searches for the form using the text input element automatically     
                // No need to locate/find the submit button     
                element.submit();           

                // This code will print the page title      
                System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());      

                driver.quit();          
     }      
}
```

I currently have the following jars added, selenium 2.53 and selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.9.0 to the build path. I'm not sure if the htmlunit is out of date or what but it seems to be giving the issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class that you use in project **needs** another class that is not on the *classpath* (selenium jar file). You should make sure to add the required jar to the classpath.

You add external jar file to java build path?

**Tutorial** [here](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2013/08/how-to-download-and-install-selenium.html).

Obs.:  If you using WTP and a server runtime, is your server runtime associated with your project.

Try it:
If you right click on your project and choose build path->configure build path and then choose the libraries tab. You should see the weblogic libraries associated here. If you do not you can click `Add Library->Server Runtime`. If the library is not there, then you first need to configure it.  `Windows->Preferences->Server->Installed runtimes`

if you use maven, sometimes, old properties saved so eclipse is confused sometimes. Try fixed that with "`mvn eclipse:clean`" command to clean old properties and then `run mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0` (for web project)

The version number shown describes the version of the JRE the class file is compatible with.

The reported major numbers are:

```
Java SE 9 = 53,
Java SE 8 = 52,
Java SE 7 = 51,
Java SE 6.0 = 50,
Java SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

To **fix** the actual problem you should try to either run the Java code with a newer version of Java JRE or specify the target parameter to the Java compiler to instruct the compiler to create code compatible with earlier Java versions.

For example, in order to generate class files compatible with Java 1.4, use the following command line:

```
javac -target 1.4 ClassWithError.java
```

Comment: yes but I don't know which jar is required that is being used by the other jar for htmlunit

Comment: Okay so I got the correct jars added to the buildpath, that took care of that original error but when I run the program I am getting this runtime error java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0